# How to fix 'Openshift has not been detected' on fabric8 via maven during deployment

Tags: maven, spring-boot, openshift, spring-tool-suite, fabric8

I would like to use Openshift's S2I-build to deploy to Openshift where it is a private cloud.
So, I am trying to deploy my **Spring Boot app** to Openshift with the command 
`mvn fabric8:deploy` but it got error and failed to build the application. It always returned `Openshift platform has been specified but Openshift has not been detected!` but I got `oc` client installed on Windows 10 and it works properly.

I searched it on Google for a long time but got no answer. Could anyone help on this issue?

Thanks.

Here is part of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <fabric8.mode>openshift</fabric8.mode>
    <fabric8.namespace>example</fabric8.namespace>
    <fabric8.username>acc</fabric8.username>
    <fabric8.password>pwd</fabric8.password>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>fmp</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resource</goal>
                        <goal>helm</goal>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The actual error:

```
[INFO] F8: Running in OpenShift mode
[INFO] F8: Using OpenShift build with strategy S2I
[WARNING] F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[INFO] F8: Running generator spring-boot
[INFO] F8: spring-boot: Using Docker image fabric8/s2i-java:2.3 as base / builder
[WARNING] F8: Cannot access cluster for detecting mode: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[ERROR] F8: Failed to execute the build [Openshift platform has been specified but Openshift has not been detected!]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  16.639 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-12T15:36:34+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:fabric8-maven-plugin:4.1.0:build (fmp) on project greeting: Failed to execute the build: Openshift platform has been specified but Openshift has not been detected! -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Maven info:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-05T03:00:29+08:00)
Maven home: C:\somewhere
Java version: 1.8.0_211, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MS950
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
PS C:\Users\somewhere\workspace\greeting>
```

Openshift info:

```
oc v3.11.16
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://openshift-sample-domain.com:8443
openshift v3.11.69
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
```

Comment: Hi, Could you please share logs with `-X` option? Maybe that would give you more info as of why plugin is not able to connect? Are you logged into your openshift cluster using `oc login`? Plugin usually reads from your `~/.kube/config` file for cluster information.

Comment: Try reading http://maven.fabric8.io/#openshift-authentication and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today and the resolution was:

- Make sure you are logged in to the openshift cluster before you try build/deploy
- Make sure the public certificate of the cluster is imported into your JRE cacerts truststore.

Let me know if you would like a concrete example of how to achieve the certificate import.